# what's the usage of the output of function GET_CLOCK_FREQUENCIES?

Tags: usb, frequency, smartcard

What's the usage of the `output` of the function `GET_CLOCK_FREQUENCIES` in the `USB:Smart Card CCID` specification,? I guess that the host can set the CCID frequency by this output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical smart card reader for an end-consumer choses its frequency on its own, after having analysized, which external clock frequency the card indicates in the TA1 byte of the ATR.

So I consider this function as informational only, to make an estimate, which frequency the reader will chose for a given card.